# Cheap Wimax Router or High power WiFi system to help impoverished area

Tags: wifi, server, wireless, web-server

I plan on making a headless FTP server with OwnCloud on a RasPi or a low end used CPU.

I need this to be accessible over a 2.5km radius. Maybe I have to use a system of multiple routers to achieve this. I am not sure what kind of hardware is required.

At first I thought some kind of high power WiMax router but I don't what to get and whatever I do see with WiMax in the title turns out to be deadly expensive.

I'm not averse to building a Project Loon type craft work to empower the area.
As a student, my objective is to empower this area that lacks proper internet connectivity with knowledge material such as an offline version of Wikipedia.

I need a router hardware recommendation. Looking for the cheapest solution with highest performance.

Comment: This would depend a lot on where exactly you want to do this. The country, and environment, will define what kind of technology is feasible. In Western countries, it is usually legal restrictions, not the hardware itself, that limits your maximum range and throughput.

Comment: Test-Location: Infopark, Kochi, Kerala, India. Project Purpouse: Multimedia File Sharing and storage over a public domain network.

Comment: Your constraints limit your options pretty badly, but given that this is likely to remain the state of affairs for your project for quite some time, what you really need to do is acquire used routers and install software like OpenWRT or dd-WRT on them, then get them set to communicate with each other in Mesh mode, and distribute them over your area. This is the only way I know of to build a reliable network with cheap equipment, because in your environment consumer grade cheap routers will fail often and you will need extremely robust connections such as those in mesh networks.